# Can there exist energy eigenstates that cannot be labelled by the good quantum numbers?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, observables

I'm trying to visually understand good quantum numbers for the example Hamiltonian of a composite system $$H = \lambda J_{1}.J_{2}$$

As I understand it, the energy of the system (assuming fixed magnitudes of angular momentum |J1| and |J2|) depends on the relative angle $\theta$ between the two angular momenta. Now I also understand that since Jz does not commute with Jx and Jy, one can't think of a perfectly well-defined direction of J, but instead a ring (with a fixed Jz but various possible Jx and Jy etc).

Therefore a mandatory condition for $J_{1}$ and $J_{2}$ to have a fixed angle between them, is that their 'rings' must be around the same axis in space.

In my notes, it says we can use the good quantum numbers $J^{2}$, $J_{1}^{2}$, $J_{2}^{2}$ and $J_{z}$ to label the various energy eigenstates.

My question is, won't there exist states where there is a fixed angle $\theta$ between $J_1$ and $J_2$ but that are not eigenstates of $J_z$ (with both of their 'rings' aligned around an axis that isn't the z-axis), therefore they would be energy eigenstates that cannot be labelled by just these quantum numbers? Is this a problem?

(e.g. here is a diagram of two angular momenta that are only defined up to their rings in J-space, but nonetheless have a fixed angle between them , and also do not have a well-defined $J_{z} = J_{1,z} + J_{2,z}$ value)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there will be energy states with off centre ring axes, but so long as they can be written as a superposition of the basis vectors involving Jz then it is fine.